Find the image of the unit circle $C =$ { $z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1$ } given a map $f(z) = z^{10} + \frac{1}{z^{10}}$
Kind of stuck on how to approach:
Given the map $f: \mathbb{C} \backslash  \left\{ 0 \right\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z) := z^{10} + z^{-10}$, find the image of the unit circle $C = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| = 1 \right\}$.
My first thought was, since the modulus of z is restricted to 1, to use the property $z^{10} + z^{-10} = 2\cos{10\theta}$ to find the image but I don't know where to go from here

Hint: What does $\theta$ vary between on the unit circle, and hence, what does $2 \cos (10 \theta )$ vary between?

Your observation is a good start. Note that the unit circle in $\Bbb{C}$ is the image of the map
$$g:\ [0,2\pi)\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ \theta\ \longmapsto\ e^{i\theta}.$$
With your observation, it follows that the image of the map $z\ \longmapsto\ z^{10}+z^{-10}$ on the unit circle is the same as the image of the composition
$$g\circ f:\ [0,2\pi)\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{C}:\ \theta\ \longmapsto\ 2\cos(10\theta).$$
This shows that the image is the real interval $[-2,2]$.

You’re missing something simple. You have this set $A=\{ x \in \mathbb{C} |\; \exists \theta \in [0,2\pi), x=2\cos(10\theta)\}$
You concluded that $f(C) \subset A$.
If you could show the other inclusion, you would be done. And that is easy too, with your observation, since every $\theta$ actually appears as an angle of a point on the unit circle.
Thus, the image set is just the image of $2\cos{(10\theta)}$ as a function from $[0,2\pi)$ which of course is $[-2,2]$.
Do you see how that’s it, if all you care about is the image set?
